# Class 'App\Controller\TwitterOAuth' not found in twitter login using 3.2

Tags: cakephp, twitter-oauth, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp ,here i am doing twitter login for my website but ,i am unable to proceede further thsi above error is coming.

I have given path like this

```html
  public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {

require_once(ROOT . '/vendor/' . DS . '/twitteroauth/' . 'twitteroauth.php');


    define('CONSUMER_KEY', '10282039035454927010');
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'ed716c05cccd08c78050e2b58b916c2fb7f');
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost/videoportal');
```

```html
 public function twitterlogin() {
        $this->layout = 'innerdefault';
        /* Start session and load library. */
        /* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        /* Get temporary credentials. */
        $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);
        //print_r($request_token); exit;
        /* Save temporary credentials to session. */
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        //echo $_SESSION['oauth_token']; exit;
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        /* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
        ///print_r($connection->http_code); exit;
        switch ($connection->http_code) {
            case 200:
                /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
                $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
                $this->redirect($url);
                break;
            default:
                /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
                echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
        }
        //exit;
    }
```

Please suggest me.Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP, you wan't to learn how to work with namespaces in php and how to use Composer. That you ask this question for that obvious error msg and that you include the file via require_once tells me that you have no idea about any of both. Do yourself a big favour and learn the *basics* before trying to develop a complete application. Namespaces are very common for a while now. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php Also CakePHP abstracts session access. You want to read about that as well, see book.cakephp.org.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install TwitterOAuth plugin with composer?